# Onnx is not working. AttributeProto is not a name error

Tags: c++, onnx

I am trying to use onnx in c++ code. But when I try to use onnx/proto_utils.h I am getting
error: 'AttributeProto' does not a name type. I am not sure is it some issue with my installation
or what. I installed onnx from source, using readme.md installation instructions. If anybody
has any clue what is wrong I would appraciate any help.

Onnx installation steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/onnx/onnx.git
cd onnx
git submodule update --init --recursive
python3 setup.py install
sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler libprotoc-dev
pip3 install onnx
```

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "onnx/onnx_pb.h"
#include "onnx/proto_utils.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello\n";
}
```

Compilation

```
g++ -DONNX_ML=1 test.cpp -o test -lprotobuf -I/home/bearnard/onnx/.setuptools-cmake-build/
```

Error Message

```
In file included from test.cpp:3:
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h:38:65: error: ‘AttributeProto’ does not name a type
   38 | template<typename T> inline std::vector<T> RetrieveValues(const AttributeProto& attr);
      |                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h:39:61: error: ‘AttributeProto’ does not name a type
   39 | template<> inline std::vector<int64_t> RetrieveValues(const AttributeProto& attr) {
      |                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h: In function ‘std::vector<T> ONNX_NAMESPACE::RetrieveValues(const int&) [with T = long int]’:
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h:40:16: error: request for member ‘ints’ in ‘attr’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
   40 |   return {attr.ints().begin(), attr.ints().end()};
      |                ^~~~
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h:40:37: error: request for member ‘ints’ in ‘attr’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
   40 |   return {attr.ints().begin(), attr.ints().end()};
      |                                     ^~~~
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h:40:49: error: could not convert ‘{<expression error>, <expression error>}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<long int>’
   40 |   return {attr.ints().begin(), attr.ints().end()};
      |                                                 ^
      |                                                 |
      |                                                 <brace-enclosed initializer list>
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h: At global scope:
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h:43:65: error: ‘AttributeProto’ does not name a type
   43 | template<> inline std::vector<std::string> RetrieveValues(const AttributeProto& attr) {
      |                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h: In function ‘std::vector<T> ONNX_NAMESPACE::RetrieveValues(const int&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h:44:17: error: request for member ‘strings’ in ‘attr’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
   44 |   return { attr.strings().begin(), attr.strings().end() };
      |                 ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h:44:41: error: request for member ‘strings’ in ‘attr’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
   44 |   return { attr.strings().begin(), attr.strings().end() };
      |                                         ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h:44:57: error: could not convert ‘{<expression error>, <expression error>}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’
   44 |   return { attr.strings().begin(), attr.strings().end() };
      |                                                         ^
      |                                                         |
      |                                                         <brace-enclosed initializer list>
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h: At global scope:
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h:47:59: error: ‘AttributeProto’ does not name a type
   47 | template<> inline std::vector<float> RetrieveValues(const AttributeProto& attr) {
      |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h: In function ‘std::vector<T> ONNX_NAMESPACE::RetrieveValues(const int&) [with T = float]’:
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h:48:17: error: request for member ‘floats’ in ‘attr’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
   48 |   return { attr.floats().begin(), attr.floats().end() };
      |                 ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h:48:40: error: request for member ‘floats’ in ‘attr’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
   48 |   return { attr.floats().begin(), attr.floats().end() };
      |                                        ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/onnx/proto_utils.h:48:55: error: could not convert ‘{<expression error>, <expression error>}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<float>’
   48 |   return { attr.floats().begin(), attr.floats().end() };
      |                                                       ^
      |                                                       |
      |                                                       <brace-enclosed initializer list>
```